# Is there way to sort the output of a dictionary by keys where numbers are the keys?

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.7

I am looking to order the output of a dictionary where the keys are numbers but I keep running into an issue where it is sorting the values as follows when I use OrderedDict from collections or the sorted() command. The output looks like this:

```
[('0', 12), ('1', 18), ('14', 26), ('18', 17), ('2', 11), ('24', 13)...]
```

Is there a way so the keys are sorted in the correct numerical order?

Thanks

Comment: Your keys are strings not numbers

Comment: That output doesn't look like a dictionary.

Comment: That is the output after I apply the sorted command

Comment: That's how strings are sorted, use numbers as keys instead

Comment: If you just want to list them sorted by the numerical value of the string, use `sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda it: int(it[0]))`.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for a "natural sort" (`pip install natsort`):

```
from natsort import natsort
from collections import OrderedDict

lst = [('0', 12), ('1', 18), ('14', 26), ('18', 17), ('2', 11), ('24', 13)]
dct = OrderedDict()
for key, value in natsort.natsorted(lst):
    dct[key] = value
print(dct)
```

This yields

```
{'0': 12, '1': 18, '2': 11, '14': 26, '18': 17, '24': 13}
```

As of `Python 3.6` the order is remembered.

Comment: `natsort` isn't part of the standard Python distribution.

Comment: @MarkRansom: `pandas`, `numpy`, `tensorflow`, etc. neither - if an external library provides additional help, why not?

Comment: Yes, but those are better known.  If you're going to suggest a package that nobody will have installed, it would be good to include a link to where to find it.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Added it to the answer.

Comment: Oh, and the property of a standard dict to keep insertion order is a recent phenomena, I forget which Python version introduced it; maybe 3.6?

Comment: @MarkRansom: Added it to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the keys into ints just for sorted().

```
lst = [('0', 12), ('1', 18), ('14', 26), ('18', 17), ('2', 11), ('24', 13)]
for e in sorted(lst, key=lambda e: int(e[0])):
    print(e)
```

Dumps:

```
('0', 12)
('1', 18)
('2', 11)
('14', 26)
('18', 17)
('24', 13)
```